OpenXML, is it possible to combine/merge/join docx
I'm struggling to merge word documents. I am able to repair these using Word.
What em I doing wrong? Is it even possible to achieve given unknown source document content?
Error produced


usecase:
I have multiple word documents that should be merged to single file.
Each document should begin on new page. Header and footer should not follow from previous document.
In some cases I would like to have duplex enabled. That means that single page document would have second blank page.
background
source document is created by someone else(template).
our code is processing template, changes some words and produces multiple copies of it.
those copies are then merged to single file.
Simplified code, just merging multiple files:
public class DocXMerger : IWordDocumentMerger
{
    public byte[] Merge(Document[] documents)
    {
        if (documents.Length == 0)
        {
            return new byte[0];
        }

        using (var mainStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mainStream.Write(documents[0].Content, 0, documents[0].Content.Length);

            using (var mainWordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mainStream, true))
            {
                if (documents[0].UseDuplex && documents[0].NumberOfPages % 2 != 0)
                {
                    mainWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertPageBreak();
                }

                mainWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertSectionBreak(false);

                var i = 0;

                foreach (var document in documents.Skip(1))
                {
                    AppendDocument(mainWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body, document, i == documents.Length - 2);
                    i++;
                }

                mainWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }

            return mainStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private void AppendDocument(Body body, Document document, bool isLastDocument)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(document.Content, 0, document.Content.Length);
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, false))
            {
                var elements = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements();

                foreach (var element in elements)
                {
                    body.AppendChild(element.CloneNode(true));
                }
            }

            if (document.UseDuplex && document.NumberOfPages % 2 != 0)
            {
                body.InsertPageBreak();
            }

            body.InsertSectionBreak(isLastDocument);
        }
    }        
}

public static class  DocXExtentions
{
    public static void InsertPageBreak(this Body body)
    {
        var run = new Run();
        run.AppendChild(new Break { Type = BreakValues.Page });
        run.AppendChild(new Break { Type = BreakValues.TextWrapping });

        body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(run));
    }

    public static void InsertSectionBreak(this Body body, bool isLastPage)
    {
        if (isLastPage)
        {
            body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
            body.AppendChild(new SectionProperties(
                new PageNumberType { Start = 1 }
            ));

            return;
        }

        var paragraphProp = new ParagraphProperties();
        var sectionProp = new SectionProperties(new PageNumberType { Start = 1 });
        var sectionType = new SectionType { Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage };

        sectionProp.AppendChild(sectionType);
        paragraphProp.AppendChild(sectionProp);

        body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(paragraphProp));
    }
}

how to run
var name = "document.docx";

var file = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath(name));

var documents = new List<Document>();
  
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // we can produce unknown amount of documents
{
    documents.Add(new Document(file, 1, true)); // document could have 2,3,4 pages; duplex or no duplex
}

var merger = new DocXMerger();
var result = merger.Merge(documents.ToArray());

File.WriteAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath($"merge_{name}"), result);

Source document File
I am using DocumentFormat.OpenXml --version 3.0.2
Open XML SDK 2.5 productivity tool validation


Yes, this should be possible. However, openxml is highly sensitive to schema specifications. It's very easy to violate the spec programmatically, and difficult/impossible to identify the error programmatically. Probably the error is something simple like missing a reference to another node, or not specifying a conditionally required property. The only way to figure this out is from divide & conquer trial and error approach. Try just inserting single page break, or just inserting single section, etc until you can identify how it's failing.

I contribute to a VS Code extension that can easily view and edit the xml parts and diff when changed by an outside program like Word it might help you find the issue with the file you're creating: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuenm18.ooxml-viewer
